# QGIS Filtering Multiple Values using Query Builder

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, query

In the "Query Builder" I can currently filter on value from the "Values List", but I'd like to be able to filter for multiple values at once.

How can I go about doing this using the SQL and "Operator's Section"?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

One method is to use the `IN` function followed by your list of values all inside brackets.

E.g.

```
"Column_Name" IN ('Value_1', 'Value_2', 'Value_N')
```

Answer (score 9):

The alternative is to use an AND/OR statement:

```
"Column_Name" = 'Value_1' OR "Column_Name" =  'Value_2'
```